# Rstudio freezes when clicking global options

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, rstudio

I've recently installed Rstudio 0.99.441 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed the latest version of R (3.20).
I want to change the background color of the console, but each time I press tools -> global options the programme freezes...Any suggestion?
I posted this question also on Rstudio support site, so if I get a solution I will post it here.
Then when I launch it from the terminal the program run without problems but I get a strange

> output:umberto@R2:~$ rstudio
>
> load glyph failed err=6 face=0x2574750, glyph=2793

when I close the program I get

> QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

Comment: Anyway I changed my OS to linux mint 17.1 and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem(1. fonts of tab's title were blurred; 2.freezing when clicking global options) after installing texlive2015 in ubuntu 14.04. In order to access texlive fonts according to the [link](http://blog.csdn.net/bendanban/article/details/23284415),
I used these 2 commands in shell (Rstudio is normal before these operation):

```
$ cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-xecjk-winfonts 09-texlive.conf
```

After tring so many methods but invalid, Occasionally, I remove the file '09-texlive.conf', and refreshed:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
$ sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

It back! I'm not sure why, but I hope it could give some hint for anyone encounter such dilemma. :D